# Literal HTML in Django without using a variable?

Tags: html, django, literals

I've got a bunch of HTML:

```
<div align="center" id="whatever">
<a href="http://www.whatever.com" style="text-decoration:none;color:black">
<img src="http://www.whatever.com/images/whatever.jpg" />
</a></div>
```

I want to output it all as literal HTML in the browser, i.e. display the above to the user. (EDIT: unfortunately I don't have access to Django variables in my template, due to the quirks of the system I'm working on, so I can't use `{{ | escape }}`.

Is there any way to do this, either using Django template tags or a special HTML tag, without having to HTML-escape it all by hand?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yup, just use the `escape` filter:

```
{{my_html|escape}}
```

**Edit**: `force_escape`:

```
{% filter force_escape %}
   ... your HTML to be escaped ...
{% endfilter %}
```

Or, from Python:

```
from django.utils.html import escape
escaped_html = escape(html_to_escape)
```

Comment: Sorry - due to the quirks of the particular system I'm working with, I don't actually have the ability to put variables in the Django template. I could escape the entire string, but it's kinda long. Is there any other way?

Comment: That's a no-op under normal conditions.  As AndiDog says in his answer, Django auto-escapes by default.  It has done since before 1.0 was released.

Comment: Ah, well, in that case, use the `force_escape` filter (see edits).

Answer (score 3):

If the HTML has to be included in the template itself, you can use the `filter` block:

```
{% filter force_escape %}
    <div align="center" id="whatever">
    <a href="http://www.whatever.com" style="text-decoration:none;color:black">
    <img src="http://www.whatever.com/images/whatever.jpg" />
    </a></div>
{% endfilter %}
```

[Documentation](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/ref/templates/builtins/#filter)

Answer (score 1):

You can always just escape it yourself if you don't wan't to do it in the template and it's somehow not escaped (let's just say the template author used `{{ var|safe }}`)

```
from django.utils.html import escape

escaped_html = escape(my_html)
```

Comment: PS: I see now, I somehow read that you don't have access to the template, not that you don't have access to variables in the template.

Answer (score 0):

Django defaults to [auto-escape](http://code.djangoproject.com/changeset/6671) context variables when inserting them (see also the [documentation](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/templates/#automatic-html-escaping)). So unless you marked the variable as safe, or use the `autoescape off` template tag, just use `{{ contextVariable }}`.