# Django template excape literal string

Tags: django-templates, escaping, html-escape-characters, django-template-filters

Basically, is something like

```
{{ ">>"|escape }}
```

possible?

I can use `{{ context_variable|escape}}` but can I use a string literal?

I want to avoid littering my template files with `&gt;`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Literal HTML in Django without using a variable?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5042820/literal-html-in-django-without-using-a-variable)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. Django treats invalid variables as an empty string. That's the case when you pass a string literal. I will have the string literal concatenated to an empty string.

There is also this answer here.
[Literal HTML in Django without using a variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5042820/literal-html-in-django-without-using-a-variable)